# How to prevent a style sheet to affect a header.php or footer.php?

Tags: headers, css, footer

I crated a footer.php and a corresponding customFooter.php. It looked great until I added header.php and customHeader.css. Now the 2 custom css files are overlaping. For example: some of the `<img>` are not aligned properly, due to the alignment of the pther css file. 
Is it possible to restrict certain css file only to a specific pphp file??

Comment: No, it's not. You should use classes to apply CSS only to specific elements and use different classes where you don't want styles to overlap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define specific stylesheets for specific PHP files.

If you are using a Child Theme, use the functions.php of the Child.

**You should use something like:**

```
function my_custom_css() {
wp_register_style( 'stylesheet_name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylesheet.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_css' );

function my_custom_css_enqueue() {
// only enqueue on product-services page slug
if ( is_page( 'my-page' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'stylesheet_name' );
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_css_enqueue' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use only one css file for my child-theme. As Jacob says I then use classes to differentiate the elements. An example:
In footer.php you have img class="myownimgleft" in customfooter.php you use img class="myownimgright"; in your css file you have .myownimgleft {float: left;} and .myownimgright {float: right;}